# Displaying Sharepoint Documents From Library on Asp.Net application

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint

Is it possible to display and view documents on an ASP.NET page which are maintained in a sharepoint library? We do not want to embed a sharepoint list or view.

The documents would be stored and maintained in and through sharepoint. The asp.net page would list (filter based on meta data) and link to the document for read only viewing.

Is this possible? 
If so what connector for the data do I use?
How would the document be served to the client?

Answer (score 0):

You can using CSOM(C#) code to get list items from document library, then using a gridview to show the data.

Articles:

[Retrieving List Items From A Specific View Using CSOM](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/retrieving-list-items-from-a-specific-view-using-csom/)

[Building an MVC application for SharePoint](http://www.tempesta.space/Link/building-an-mvc-application-for-sharepoint)